# How to update item properties for an existing document found by search with CSOM?

Tags: 2013, rest, csom, enterprise

You don't know which library it resides in, nor site, nor site collection. The only entry point is the search center URL or _api/Search endpoint.

The problem is that when you retrieve the File it is also agnostic of parent folder/list/web/site. Anyone solved it already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got you right, you search for documents using CSOM/REST.
Let's assume you try to use 'query' method of '_api/Search' endpoint.
All you need is to define selectproperties for query:
[image: Search Query params]

You may need SPWebUrl to construct request to REST endpoint for item properties.
Let me assume you're using on-premises SharePoint Server 2013 installation.
In this case you have to create new text managed property in Search Service Application's schema (don't forget to mark it as Retrievable):
[image: OnPrem crawled prop]

Also don't forget to do full crawl after property has been added.

SharePoint Online already has it mapped to "SPWebUrl, owstaxIdSPLocationSite" (not enough reputation to post another link :) )

Hope this help.